# Is there a pseudo element for the scrollbar buttons when the scrollbar reaches the content end?

Tags: css

Im trying to figure out if it is possible to select the arrows when you cannot scroll any further in the designated direction. Has anyone come across a pseudo selector for this case ?

[image]

Comment: No there is not

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:
You can check if the user has scrolled down to the bottom via jquery.
I have inserted some css code about the scrollbar manipulation. Now you just have to combine them. Good luck!

**Scrollbar customizations are not fully supported on Firefox and some other browsers**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

```css
    .container {
    display: block;
    height: 800px;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 16px;
      border: 5px solid white;

    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: #b0b0b0;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      border: 0.05em solid #eeeeee;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: #bbbbbb;
    }
    /* Buttons */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
      background-color: #bbbbbb;
      display: block;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 13px;
      width: 16px;
    }
    /* Up */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
      border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
      border-color: transparent transparent #555555 transparent;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
      border-color: transparent transparent #777777 transparent;
    }
    /* Down */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
      border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
      border-color: #555555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:single-button:increment:hover {
      border-color: #777777 transparent transparent transparent;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah I realize that jQuerry will do the job ;) I was just hoping there was a selector *sigh*